# R Markdown stops rendering when encountering a chunk with base R graphics

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, rlang

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.2.1  fastmap_1.1.0   cli_3.3.0       htmltools_0.5.3 tools_4.2.1     yaml_2.3.5     
 [7] rmarkdown_2.14  gdata_2.18.0.1  knitr_1.39      xfun_0.31       digest_0.6.29   rlang_1.0.2    
[13] gtools_3.9.3    evaluate_0.15
```

I have an issue where RMarkdowns stop knitting (without error) when encountering chunks with graphics/plots.

I experience this issue even with the default RMarkdown with `summary(cars)` and `plot(pressure)`. However, when I comment out the `plot(pressure)` chunk, the .html file is rendered successfully and I get an output instantaneously.

I was getting the following error as well:

```
Error in .rs.parsePackageDependencies(contents, extension) :
object 'partition_yaml_front_matter' not found
```

and I tried `remotes::install_version("rlang", "1.0.2")` as suggested here:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11552

But that hasn't solved this issue.

Any help or tips appreciated...

Comment: Try adding `library(rlang)` and `library(rmarkdown)` to your RMD.